# Rails: start writing tests late in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd

We've built a fully functional v. 1 application in Ruby on Rails without writing a single test. We'd like to write all necessary tests so that the next version can be developed in that fashion.

Where should we start? We've done research on how to write tests but they don't seem to cover how to start when so much of the application already exists.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Rewrite it all from scratch if you have the time. That's always a good exercise if you have an abondance of time... Unlikely I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would attempt to determine the most basic set of acceptance tests you can construct to simply satisfy all of the primary goals of the site. Then, I would add a few more, to more strenuously exercise the edge cases of the most complex portions. Make sure that anything involving money is very well covered, possibly adding a few unit tests for items like that (financial/mission critical) only. That should get you up and running fairly quickly, in terms of both developer time and test execution speed. Then, simply add new tests using your ideal process as new bugs are discovered and features added.

Comment: i'd recommend: make your tests fail (logically!) at first by commenting out a few lines of crucial code, so you know, that the tests really cover what you intended to test.

Comment: Good call - I completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

On a pre-existing application I would start from the top down. That is start by writing tests for your views/controllers. Make sure your interfaces are tested, then go deeper and do your unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I would see what Michael Hartl does in the great Rails Tutorial as he progresses through the app, and adds tests for new models, views, and controllers.

This will give you good ideas on how to examine your existing UI and backend code and design some basic tests.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book